# Unable to cast object of Sytem.String to type

Tags: c#, .net

I'm receiving this messaage;

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'main.Entitys.Department'.
```

for this piece of code;

```
return ((Department)department_ComboBox.SelectedItem).ToInt();
```

I have a combobox with many `Department` objects within it, and i'm trying to retrieve the ID of the selected item using this method within the `Department` class;

```
public int ToInt()
    {
        return dID;
    }
```

I don't get why it's saying it can't cast a string object when I'm trying to return an int?!

Comment: post the code where you are filling the DropDown

Comment: What framework are you using here? WinForms, Web, Wpf, etc...

Comment: @Mr. I was too stubborn to check that, sorry my fault! Thanks though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(Department)department_ComboBox.SelectedItem // Here is the Mistake
```

The `selectedItem` is `String` check it, it is **NOT** a `Department`.

Comment: Indeed it was! I was adding a it's variable instead of the actual object! arrghhhhhhhhhhh! Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I'm missing some pieces there, but if all you want to do is return an int, assuming the department_ComboBox.SelectedItem is an integer, just conver it or cast it.  To conver it, simply do

```
Convert.toInt32(department_ComboBox.SelectedItem);
```

Comment: NOT! `the public int ToInt()
    {
        return dID;
    } `
is to return the Id of the Department!, he expected that the `SelectedItem` was a `Department` and the `ToInt(`) is for returning the dID i guess is the Department ID